# Pandas Resampling: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Tags: python, pandas

Please, help me.
I want to resample based on 1D.
I have following format of data.
I want to use resampling in pandas.

I want to resample based on Date and product and also fill the missing values.

But I keep getting this mistake: I tried like 5 options and mistake only changes after "instance of": I saw there Multiindex, Index.

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

```
product value   date
A   1.52    2016-01-01
A   NULL    2016-09-20
A   1.33    2018-08-02
B   1.30    2016-01-01
B   NULL    2017-01-02
B   1.54    2017-03-10
B   2.08    2017-06-28
B   2.33    2018-08-02
```

I put these data into

```
df.reset_index().set_index('date','sku')  
df= df.groupby('product').resample('1D')['value'].ffill().bfill().ffill()
```

I tried also:

```
df = df.set_index(['date','sku'])
df = df.set_index('date','sku')
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['date','sku'])
```

Please, can you explain me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Today morning it was working on these data and the command from Jezrael:

```
df = df.set_index('date').groupby('product').resample('1D')['value'].ffill()

    product value   date
   0    A   1.52    2016-01-01
   1    A   NaN 2016-09-20 
   2    A   1.87    2018-08-02
   3    B   2.33    2016-01-01
   4    B   NaN 2016-09-20
   5    B   4.55    2018-08-02
```

But suddenly it doesnt anymore.
Now I have Index in the error statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need `DatetimeIndex` if working with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html), also `bfill` is omited because if some only `NaN`s groups is possible these data are replaced from another groups:

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes 
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index('date').groupby('product').resample('1D')['value'].ffill()
print (df)
product  date      
A        2016-01-01    1.52
         2016-01-02    1.52
         2016-01-03    1.52
         2016-01-04    1.52
         2016-01-05    1.52
         2016-01-06    1.52
         2016-01-07    1.52
         2016-01-08    1.52
         2016-01-09    1.52
         2016-01-10    1.52
         2016-01-11    1.52
         2016-01-12    1.52
```

Changed **sample** for better explanation:

```
print (df)
  product  value       date
0       A   1.52 2016-01-01
1       A    NaN 2016-01-03
2       B    NaN 2017-01-02
3       B    NaN 2017-01-03
4       C   1.54 2017-03-10
5       C   2.08 2017-03-12
6       C   2.33 2017-03-14
```

---

```
df1 = df.set_index('date').groupby('product').resample('1D')['value'].ffill()
print (df1)
product  date      
A        2016-01-01    1.52
         2016-01-02    1.52
         2016-01-03     NaN < NaN is not changed because in original data
B        2017-01-02     NaN <- only NaN group B
         2017-01-03     NaN
C        2017-03-10    1.54
         2017-03-11    1.54
         2017-03-12    2.08
         2017-03-13    2.08
         2017-03-14    2.33
Name: value, dtype: float64

df11 = df.set_index('date').groupby('product').resample('1D')['value'].ffill().bfill()
print (df11)
product  date      
A        2016-01-01    1.52
         2016-01-02    1.52
         2016-01-03    1.54 <- back filling value from group C
B        2017-01-02    1.54 <- back filling value from group C
         2017-01-03    1.54 <- back filling value from group C
C        2017-03-10    1.54
         2017-03-11    1.54
         2017-03-12    2.08
         2017-03-13    2.08
         2017-03-14    2.33
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, this is so great! Thanks for great explanation. I dont know how it previously could work... Just to clarify, I need to set index only to time and than group by the value that I want to resample, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: But - do you think it is possible my Jupyter is against me? Once it is working once it is not even though I have the same data set?

Comment: @HeadOverFeet - hmmm, maybe some changes in data? If use `print (df.head())` it always return same dataset?

Comment: I am testing it on the same like I posted here by using this: df = df.set_index('date').groupby('product').resample('1D')['value'].ffill()

Comment: I am starting to feel really strange :D once it works, once it doesnt

Comment: Well, I feel that pandas doesnt create DateTimeIndex, when I check isinstance(df.index, pd.DatetimeIndex) = it returns False

Comment: @HeadOverFeet - So need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` as first step.

Comment: ! Thanks! I was just googling it! Great. I dont understand why is did it when I first logged into the system. Oh, dear! Thanks

Comment: @jezrael one of the best answers I've seen on the site. Awesome! Thanks!